# 2 different Laravel 5.6 installation

Tags: php, laravel

I worked with a Laravel programmer. We did a project together. I got back-end service from him. Now I installed Laravel 5.6 on my server to activate that project again after 3 years. Laravel version on my localhost is 5.6. However, when I compare the laravel files on the server with the ones on my computer, I see that there are differences even in the default files.

1-) What is the reason for this? 
2-) I was thinking of running the website by detecting the differences and downloading the ones that are not on the server from my computer. Is this a correct way?

Because I tried to upload the files on my computer to the internet and run them, but I couldn't. I thought that I could make a brand new installation and run the files that are not there by uploading them to my server from my computer.

**My server details: CentOS, Plesk CP and i am working with PHP version 7.3.33**

Composer details (localhost)

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.0",
    "cknow/laravel-money": "^1.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

**Composer details (new installation on server)**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Comment: Can you tell us which default files changed ? Some of them are subject to changes when you work on your project. (like routes, kernel, providers, all the app folder) Dont list files in vendor and app/boostrap. Maybe you have an older version of the project on your machine ?

Comment: I have checked the versions both of them with `php artisan --version`. Both of them 5.6.40 and i am sure we were working on version 5.6.40. I am comparing the files with WinMerge program. It is comparing all files and shows the different lines. Almost all folders and files has differences. Not big differences but it has differences.

Comment: Are you sure the code is different ? Sometimes when you transfer files between Windows/Linux some characters can change like line-endings. And what do you mean by "I installed Laravel 5.6 on my server" ?

Comment: I am exactly sure these are different. The file names are same but inside of them different. I have intalled custom version with `composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.6.*" ProjectName`. I don't know what should i do. On my webserver i have fresh installed laravel. And i have project on my localhost. How will I know which files to upload to the internet? I want to run the system on a fresh install.

Comment: To deploy a Laravel project you don't have to run `composer create-project`. Just copy your project files to your server. Then you have to run some commands. Check for "How to deploy laravel 5.6" First you have to check if you have a dump of your database.